# Vue 3 - use props string to load component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have following component:

```
<script setup>

import {computed, onMounted, ref, watch} from "vue";
import {useDialogStore} from "@/store/dialog";
import TableSwitcher from "@/components/Dialogs/Components/TableSwitcher.vue"

let emit = defineEmits(['confirmDialogConfirmed', 'confirmDialogClose'])
let dialogStore = useDialogStore()

let question = computed(() => dialogStore.dialogQuestion)
let mainComponent = ref('')

let props = defineProps({
  open: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    default: 'main-dialog'
  },
  component: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
})

watch(props, (newValue, oldValue) => {

    mainComponent.value = props.component

    console.log(mainComponent);

      if(newValue.open === true)
      {
        dialog.showModal()
      }

    },
    {
      deep:true
    }
);

let dialog = ref();

let closeDialog = (confirmAction = false) =>
{
  dialog.close()
  dialogStore.close(confirmAction)
}

onMounted(() => {
  dialog = document.getElementById(props.id);
});

</script>

<template>
  <dialog :id="id">
    <component :is="mainComponent" ></component>
  </dialog>
</template>
```

For activating component I am using this:

```
<main-dialog
    v-if="component"
    :component="component"
    :open="true">
</main-dialog>
```

**component** value is created on click and passed as a prop to the main component. When I click to activate this component I am getting following error:

**`Invalid vnode type when creating vnode`**

When I hard code the component name for the **mainComponent** var the component is loaded correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what `component` value is and why it causes an error

Comment: why don't use slots?

If you need to pass it as array you need to make sure, that the component is registered correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to solve that. I think in your case it would make sense to use [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html). But if you want to keep your approach you can globally define your components in your Vue app.

### without slots

```js
const app = createApp({});

// define components globally as async components:
app.component('first-component', defineAsyncComponent(async () => import('path/to/your/FirstComponent.vue'));
app.component('second-component', defineAsyncComponent(async () => import('path/to/your/SecondComponent.vue'));

app.mount('#app');
```

Then you can use strings and fix some bugs in your component:

- Don’t use ids, instead use a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to access the dialog element
- Use `const` instead of `let` for non-changing values.
- props are already reactive so you can use the props also directly inside your template and they will be updated automatically when changed from the outside.

```js
// inside <script setup>

import {computed, onMounted, ref, watch} from "vue";
import {useDialogStore} from "@/store/dialog";
import TableSwitcher from "@/components/Dialogs/Components/TableSwitcher.vue"

// use const instead of let, as the values are not changing:
const emit = defineEmits(['confirmDialogConfirmed', 'confirmDialogClose'])

const props = defineProps({
  open: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    default: 'main-dialog'
  },
  component: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const dialogStore = useDialogStore()
const question = computed(() => dialogStore.dialogQuestion);
const dialog = ref(null);

watchPostEffect(
  () => {
    if(props.open) {
      dialog.value?.showModal()
    }
  },
  // call watcher also on first lifecycle:
  { immediate: true }
);

let closeDialog = (confirmAction = false) => {
  dialog.value?.close()
  dialogStore.close(confirmAction)
}
```

```html
<!-- the sfc template -->
<dialog ref="dialog">
  <component :is="props.component" />
</dialog>
```

### with slots

```html
<!-- use your main-dialog -->
<main-dialog :open="open">
  <first-component v-if="condition"/>
  <second-component v-else />
</main-dialog>
```

```html
<!-- template of MainDialog.vue -->
<dialog ref="dialog">
  <slot />
</dialog>
```